# Getting "org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found" error though I have the same version installed in my system.How to resolve this?

Tags: sbt

```
set -e pipefail; sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -DchiselVersion="latest.release" "run Parity --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd " | tee Parity.out
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
```

problems summary ::
WARNINGS

```
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

ERRORS
        Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml

```
    Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.pom

    Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8
```

Answer (score 2):

this might be proxy issue.
Edit $SBT_HOME/conf directory/sbtconfig.txt file and add following entries:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy server>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port>
-Dhttp.proxyUser=<username>
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=<password>
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy server>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy port>
-Dhttps.proxyUser=<username>
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=<password>
-Dftp.proxyHost=<proxy server>
-Dftp.proxyPort=<proxy port>
-Dftp.proxyUser=<username>
-Dftp.proxyPassword=<password>
```

Notes:

1. https settings are necessary as many urls referred by the SBT are https based.
2. Don't include "http://" in the  value

Comment: I tried this & it still doesn't seem to work. Is there any other workaround for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Seems like the issue is with the java that is used. By mistake my environment was pointing to jre rather than jdk. After pointing to right JAVA_HOME as below, the sbt clean package compile worked fine.

[root@spark-sql-perf]# update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

### Selection    Command

*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.ppc64le (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.ppc64le/jre/bin/java)
   2           java-1.7.0-openjdk.ppc64le (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.0.el7_3.ppc64le/jre/bin/java)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: q

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

### Selection    Command

*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.ppc64le (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.ppc64le/jre/bin/java)
   2           java-1.7.0-openjdk.ppc64le (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.0.el7_3.ppc64le/jre/bin/java)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: ^C

[root@spark-sql-perf]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.ppc64le/

[root@spark-sql-perf]# export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH